# How can open I unconditionally to open the open_basedir?

Tags: php, open-basedir

It's PHP question. 
I set open_basedir, and it is not more possible for access for the folder in the hierarchy of the bottom even if I make it accessible for a specific directory.

For example, when it was the directory of the hierarchy that said /home/user1/test/example/

open_basedir=.: /home/user1/test/

When I set  the file arranged right under a test/ folder can open, but cannot open the file posted right under example/.

open_basedir=.: /home/user1/test/: /home/user1/test/example/

is OK.
but .
Could you give me a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to ensure access is set correctly in apache httpd.conf

Comment: What environment/os are you on?